# C# encoding issue, Character '¤' result to '?'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, character-encoding

I have a C# program where I stored a long SQL query in a resource file (sql.resx).

In my query I have a special currency character (`¤`). When my program gets the query from the resource file and executes it on SQL Server, the currency character (`¤`) appears as an unsupported character. On appending character `¤` to the result it appears as `�` instead of `¤`.

For me it seems like an encoding issue in C#.

Here's an excerpt from the query, where things are correct:

```
    and tb.beward = b.beward and tb.beroom = b.beroom and tb.beidnr = b.beidnr
    and wp.wpspecialbranch = c.tunnus
and ((b.beward + '¤' + b.beroom + '¤' + b.beidnr) LIKE @SCHEDULE

        and 
        ((tb.beward + '¤' + tb.beroom + '¤' + tb.beidnr) LIKE @SCHEDULE))
```

And here's what I'm observing:

```
    and tb.beward = b.beward and tb.beroom = b.beroom and tb.beidnr = b.beidnr
    and wp.wpspecialbranch = c.tunnus
and ((b.beward + '�' + b.beroom + '�' + b.beidnr) LIKE @SCHEDULE

        and 
        ((tb.beward + '�' + tb.beroom + '�' + tb.beidnr) LIKE @SCHEDULE))
```

[image]

This happens when I copy the query from debug mode and paste in SQL Server Management Studio.

**Note:** It was working fine on my server few days before, but isn't working now. There must be some changes happened on my server, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 4):

I think there are two issues here.

First, in SQL Server, string literals with wide characters need the `N` prefix:

```
b.reward + N'¤'
```

Second, the character encoding for the *.resx file is probably wrong, or you'd at least see the character in the window, even if Sql Server didn't read it properly.

If this was working a few days ago, possibly someone opened and saved the file with a program that only knows how to do ASCII, and your special character was mangled. You'll need to fix the file.

If this came from the Visual Studio debug window — which is notorious for mangling values while trying to be "helpful" — you might not even be looking in the right place.

---

I also have three items for you separate from the question.

Looking at the SQL, this isn't gonna perform well. The concatenation going on here makes any indexes on those columns worthless. You will get **much** better performance... probably orders of magnitude, if you structure the query to not require concatenating those columns. At least, possibly a computed column with a FULL-TEXT index, could make this query drastically faster.

Logically, the SQL is also doing extra work. If the `beward`, `beroom`, `beidnr` columns already match between the two tables, you only need to concatenated and test ONE of them against the `@SCHEDULE` input. They have the same values, so if one matches (or not), the other must have the same result.

In the future, please *PASTE THE CODE* into your question. Images don't work as well here. It saves you work, too.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server

You need to use the datatype Nvarchar which is able to store unicode characters.

To declare a string literal as nvarchar you need to prefix it with N', without it is just a normal varchar. Varchars allow only characters in the specified underlying collation.

```
b.reward + N'¤'
```